# Selenium IDE problems with a new:from XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, selenium, firebug, selenium-ide

I have a problem with a Xpath I want to use in Selenium IDE.
First it is strange, that when I right-click on the element, the Selenium Options do not show up.

Second, if I inspect the element with Firebug an copy the XPath, the result is this:

```
//html/body/div/div[4]/new:form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[17]/td[3]/a
```

If I insert this path in Selenium an click on "find" I get the massage that the Locator is not found. 
When I run it it says: [error] invalid Xpath[2]:(then the path)

There is no problem finding

```
//html/body/div/div[4]/
```

I think the problem is the "new:form" part but I did not get why?!

I have no access to the code. But when I remove the "new" in firebug it works.
Is there any solution for this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XPath provided by Firebug element `form` is defined in some namespace, Firebug uses `new` as prefix. I have no idea does Selenium support XPath with namespaces. Anyway, you can slightly modify given XPath, using `*` instead of `new:form`, i.e.:

```
//html/body/div/div[4]/*[local-name(.) = 'form']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[17]/td[3]/a
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I know where the new:form comes from. I already had the idea to use the * but I had no idea how. I will try it tomorrow at work.:)

Comment: Thanks that worked =)
Only with the *. Very simple but effectiv. I think the ':' was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

At the time this question was written, there was no proper support in Selenium for namespaces within XPath expressions. However, [that has since been changed](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1694). Since some time ([around March 2015](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/4f5f96d92d12197d85d6faadc0bfb57c6a661c29)), you can use the namespace prefixes as they appear in the document to select elements.

Before this, it was quite a bit harder and you needed a solution like in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13167624/111575). Now you can just use the expression as given in the original question:

```
//html/body/div/div[4]/new:form....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install **Firepath** which is an **extension of Firebug**.This will give you more clear xpath.

Comment: Thank you. Good to now about Firepath. I will try it tomorrow at work. :)

Comment: I installed Firepath but it was not able to find the 'new:form' Xpath either. Maybe I handled it wrong.